# How to get all innerHTML of <svg> with all nested <g> <path>?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svg

I have an element:

```
<div>    
    <svg>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

The problem is: when I get `mySvgElement.innerHTML`, I receive only `<svg><path></path></svg>`. `<g>`s are ignored.

And I still can't find the way how to get them. Is there's a way to do it? 
**No jQuery**

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Could you create an example on something like jsfiddle.net?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zerho1yc/ , when i try something like this it works, cant reproduce what you saying

Comment: @Fox I am unable to repro this. But I have added a working answer.

Comment: @Fox Use Stack Snippets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the below code I am able to get the full HTML structure.

```html
<div id="svgCont">
  <svg>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<script>
  var d = document.getElementById("svgCont");
  console.log(d.innerHTML);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id = "mySvgElement">    
    <svg>
        <g>
            <g>
                <path></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<script>
  console.log($("#mySvgElement").innerHTML);
</script>
```

Above Code working fine

Output :

[image]